# How to pass data from one view to other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I Have a table, there i have a details hyperlink on click of which i m showing a new table on same page in other div. The details Hyperlink has 3 input parameters based on which a service method gets triggered and I get data in the data. Now i have this task to show the 2nd grid on a new page. I m not sure how to do it.
Please help.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover  ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Organization No</th>
                            <th>Contract No</th>
                            <th>Company Name</th>
                            <th>Plan No</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>View Detail</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr ng-repeat="mas in vm | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"  data-ng-class="{active1:$index==selectedRow}" data-ng-click="rowHighilited($index)">
                    <td>{{mas.startDate | amDateFormat:&#39;YYYY-MM-DD&#39;}} </td>
                        <td>{{mas.organizationNumber}}</td>
                        <td>{{mas.contractNumber}} </td>
                        <td>{{mas.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{mas.planNumber}} </td>
                        <td>{{mas.description}} </td>
                        <td><span><a href="#" ng-click="getErrorDetailBySearch(mas.productAccountOid,mas.planNumber,mas.migrationRunID)">Details</a></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

//getErrorDetailBySearch(mas.productAccountOid,mas.planNumber,mas.migrationRunID)it calls the function to bring data an binds it to the below div.//

```
<div ng-show="IsVisible">
            <div ng-show="vm1.length &gt; 0 &amp;&amp; !loading">
                <h2>Error Detail</h2>
                <br />

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover  table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                    <th>Contract Number</th>
                                    <th>Plan Number</th>
                                    <th>Business Error Message</th>
                                    <th>System Error Details</th>


                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr ng-repeat="mas in vm1">
                                <td>{{mas.contractNumber}} </td>
                                <td>{{mas.planNumber}} </td>
                                <td>{{mas.businessErrorMsg }} </td>
                                <td>{{mas.systemErrorMsg}} </td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am able to call a new page Called as ErrorDeatils but i dont know how to pass data b/w the pages.
This is controller written for 1st page

```
$scope.getErrorDetailBySearch = function (productAccountOid, planNr, migrationrunid) {

            var path = "/Utilities/Error";
            $location.path(path.replace(/\s+/g, ""));

        };


var onSuccess = function (response) {
            $scope.vm1 = response;
            if ($scope.vm1 < 1) {
                messageService.noDataFound();
            }
        }
$scope.getErrorDetailBySearch = function (productAccountOid, planNr,migrationrunid, skipFormValidate) {
            if (skipFormValidate || b360FormsService.validateForm($scope.ViewErrorDetail)) {
                errorService.globalproductAccountOid = productAccountOid;
                errorService.globalplanNr = planNr;
                errorService.globalmigrationrunid = migrationrunid;
                $scope.loading = true;
                repositoryService.getErrorDetailBySearch(productAccountOid, planNr, migrationrunid).$promise.then(onSuccess, onError).finally(function () {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                });

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can pass data both as query parameters or route params

1. Query Parameters

Lets say you have path "/errorDetails" and you want to pass "param" with value "10", then you can use $location.path() as follows:

```
$location.path("/errorDetails").search({param: 10});
```

and you can access value of "param" on resultant page's controller as:

```
$location.search().param;
```

2. Route Parameters

   For using route params you will need to change your route configurations and you path will be like:

   ```
    $routeProvider
       .when('/errorDetails/:param', {
           title: 'Error Details',
           templateUrl: 'path/to/errorDetails.html'
       });
   ```

Now you can send param using $location.path as follow:

```
    $location.path("/errorDetails/"+param);
```

And you can access route parameter on resultant page's controller as follows:

```
   $routeParams.param
```

Comment: these are the changes i have done, but i dont know why i m gettig redirected back to my home page $routeProvider.when("/Utilities/Error/:productAccountOid/planNr/:planNr/migrationrunid/:migrationrunid",
       {
           templateUrl: "app/templates/views/utilities/ErrorDetail.html",
           title: "View Error Detail",
           controller: "ErrorDetailController",
           resolve: {
            title: function() { return "View Plan MAS Link"; }
        }
    });

Comment: Which method are you using? and redirection to home page is due to some error in code  - incorrect path, missing controller, or so..

Comment: i got the values in my url http://localhost:60523/Utilities/Error/554462/planNr/002/migrationrunid/1.. can u please guide me how do i now get these values binded to my grid.Any sample code snippet

Comment: As far as I can understand, you would have received a json object as {Error: 554462, planNr: 002, migrationrunid: 1}, But you are using an array of objects in your grid. Why?